# WPF XAML DatePicker DisplayDateStart

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I know you can set the DisplayDateEnd in XAML by doing the following

```
DisplayDateEnd="{x:Static sys:DateTime.Today}"
```

Is it possible to set the DisplayDateStart to only go back 6 days including today through XAML

Here is how I am achieving this currently

```
dpLogDates.DisplayDateStart = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-6);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create your own static property for this.

```
 public static class DtHelper
  {
    public static DateTime myTime
    {
      get { return DateTime.Today.AddDays(-6); }
    }
  }
```

In XAML

```
DisplayDateEnd="{x:Static app:DtHelper.myTime}"
```